# Grunt Uglify Leading to Error

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I started using Grunt to build my app; used the uglify module to minify my scripts . Loading the minified file leads to an error
Original : https://github.com/mayur-arora/imageDrive/blob/master/scripts/content_script.js

Minified:https://github.com/mayur-arora/imageDrive/blob/master/scripts/content_script.min.js

If I manually add "})" at the end of the minified file, it works. But should I have to do this ? Why does Uglify get it wrong ?
Similar is the case with 
Original:https://github.com/mayur-arora/imageDrive/blob/master/scripts/imageDrive.js
and 
minified:https://github.com/mayur-arora/imageDrive/blob/master/scripts/imageDrive.min.js
This one has - unexpected token var

Comment: Which uglify specifically? Directly, or through something like require.js? Code?

Comment: grunt-contrib-uglify

Answer (score 0):

I used 'remove-logging' before 'uglify' and now it works fine. Uglify followed by 'remove-logging' was causing this.